# Plsql XML parsing - namespace problem again :-(

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have a problem with my select. The tag where I would like to get the value of has a namespace, and later on, the namespace can be different, so I can not hardcode it.

So far the '//*[local-name()=' syntax is working, unless the tag has a namespace which i would like to get the value from.

The values are coming back now a null.

```
select 
test.test_customer_id,
test.test_customer_id_2
 
from (
       select column_value
       from XMLTABLE(q'~//*[local-name()='ResponseData']~'
       PASSING
            (select xmltype('<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                               <S:Body>
                                  <V2 xmlns:ns27="http://testnamespace">
                                     <ResponseData>
                                        <CustomerData>
                                           <ns27:TestCustomerId>27295343</ns27:TestCustomerId>
                                           <ns27:TestCustomerId2>27295343</ns27:TestCustomerId2>
                                        </CustomerData>
                                     </ResponseData>
                                  </V2>
                               </S:Body>
                            </S:Envelope>'
                            )
              from dual))) dlcp,
       XMLTABLE('//CustomerData' PASSING dlcp.column_value COLUMNS
                test_customer_id VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'TestCustomerId',
                test_customer_id_2 VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'TestCustomerId2') test;
```

Can I fix this without declaring and hardcoding ns27 namespace?

Answer (score 2):

If you really won't know the namespaces then you can wildcard the namespace with `*`:

```
-- wildcards
select 
test.test_customer_id,
test.test_customer_id_2
 
from (
       select column_value
       from XMLTABLE(q'~//*[local-name()='ResponseData']~'
       PASSING
            (select xmltype('<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                               <S:Body>
                                  <V2 xmlns:ns27="http://testnamespace">
                                     <ResponseData>
                                        <CustomerData>
                                           <ns27:TestCustomerId>27295343</ns27:TestCustomerId>
                                           <ns27:TestCustomerId2>27295343</ns27:TestCustomerId2>
                                        </CustomerData>
                                     </ResponseData>
                                  </V2>
                               </S:Body>
                            </S:Envelope>'
                            )
              from dual))) dlcp,
       XMLTABLE('//*:CustomerData' PASSING dlcp.column_value COLUMNS
                test_customer_id VARCHAR2(100) PATH '*:TestCustomerId',
                test_customer_id_2 VARCHAR2(100) PATH '*:TestCustomerId2') test;
```

| TEST_CUSTOMER_ID | TEST_CUSTOMER_ID_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 27295343 | 27295343 |

You can also simplify to a single XMLTable call:

```
select 
test.test_customer_id,
test.test_customer_id_2
from XMLTABLE(q'~//*[local-name()='ResponseData']/*:CustomerData~'
    PASSING
        (select xmltype('<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                               <S:Body>
                                  <V2 xmlns:ns27="http://testnamespace">
                                     <ResponseData>
                                        <CustomerData>
                                           <ns27:TestCustomerId>27295343</ns27:TestCustomerId>
                                           <ns27:TestCustomerId2>27295343</ns27:TestCustomerId2>
                                        </CustomerData>
                                     </ResponseData>
                                  </V2>
                               </S:Body>
                            </S:Envelope>'
                            )
              from dual)
    COLUMNS
        test_customer_id VARCHAR2(100) PATH '*:TestCustomerId',
        test_customer_id_2 VARCHAR2(100) PATH '*:TestCustomerId2'
) test;
```

| TEST_CUSTOMER_ID | TEST_CUSTOMER_ID_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 27295343 | 27295343 |

or:

```
select 
test.test_customer_id,
test.test_customer_id_2
from (select xmltype('<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                               <S:Body>
                                  <V2 xmlns:ns27="http://testnamespace">
                                     <ResponseData>
                                        <CustomerData>
                                           <ns27:TestCustomerId>27295343</ns27:TestCustomerId>
                                           <ns27:TestCustomerId2>27295343</ns27:TestCustomerId2>
                                        </CustomerData>
                                     </ResponseData>
                                  </V2>
                               </S:Body>
                            </S:Envelope>'
                            ) as xml
              from dual) dlcp
cross apply XMLTABLE(q'~//*[local-name()='ResponseData']/*:CustomerData~'
    PASSING dlcp.xml
    COLUMNS
        test_customer_id VARCHAR2(100) PATH '*:TestCustomerId',
        test_customer_id_2 VARCHAR2(100) PATH '*:TestCustomerId2'
) test;
```

| TEST_CUSTOMER_ID | TEST_CUSTOMER_ID_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 27295343 | 27295343 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lZSTgb7S)

Comment: Oh wow, that was superfast, and all of the 3 responses are correct. Good Job Bro! <3